# Error Encountered: Chrome Binary Not Found When Running Auto-GPT in Google Colab

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory, autogpt

I'm encountering an issue while running Auto-GPT in Google Colab. The error message is as follows:

```bash
NEXT ACTION:  COMMAND = browse_website ARGUMENTS = {'url':  
 'https://www.hkex.com.hk/Products/Listed-Derivatives/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-(HSI)/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures?sc_lang=en', 
'question': 'Hang Seng Index future data'}

AUTHORISED COMMANDS LEFT: 8 /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found /bin/sh: 1:     
google-chrome-stable: not found /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-beta: not found /bin/sh: 1:     
google-chrome-dev: not found SYSTEM: Command browse_website returned:  
Error: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? I would highly appreciate any assistance!

I've attempted to modify a .env file within the Auto-GPT directory and set the following, but this method was unsuccessful:

> `# USE_WEB_BROWSER=firefox`